# что означает "a, b = b, a + b"?

Tags: python

Изучаю язык, вопрос о последовательности чисел Фиббоначи, решение типа такое:

```
def fib(n):
    print("Последовательность чисел Фиббоначи, не привышающих ", n)
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b),
        a, b = b, a + b
```

Что означает написанное в последней строке?

Comment: 1) высчитывается `b`; 2) высчитывается `a+b`; 3) в `a` попадает высчитанное ранее значение `b`; 4) в `b` попадает высчитанное  ранее значение `a+b`

Comment: Большое спасибо, но не понятно действие 1) - что значит высчитывается b, и как высчитанные ранее значения попадают в другие значения (может спрошу по другому, что именно в этой строке сделано так чтобы старые значения менялись на новые). Может вопрос и дурацкий, не обессудьте, но чтобы изучать дальше нужно понимать механизм пройденного.

Comment: Это упрощенное объяснение, там на самом деле на первой итерации создается кортеж из рассчитанных значений `b` и `a+b`, а затем этот кортеж раскрывается на переменные `a` и `b`

Comment: отступление: `print(b),` должно быть просто `print(b)` или (ближе к `print b,` из Питона 2) `print(b, end=' ')`

Comment: формально,  [описание синтаксиса присвоения в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)

Answer (score 8):

В последней строке используется tuple unpacking.

Рассмотрим на работу этого механизма на примере:
пусть `a = 1` и `b = 2`.

---

Так как для создания кортежа указывать скобки не обязательно, то запись

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

эквивалентна

```
(a, b) = (b, a + b)
```

---

Cначала вычисляется правая часть выражения:
так как `b == 2` и `a + b == 1 + 2 == 3`, мы получаем кортеж `(2, 3)` (об этом писал в своём комментарии [@BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438740/%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-a-b-b-a-b#comment459324_438740)). В этот момент исходная запись становится эквивалентна записи

```
a, b = 2, 3
```

*Замечу, что подобная конструкция уже использовалась в приведённом вами коде для инициализации переменных `a` и `b`*

Далее элементы правого кортежа присваиваются в переменные, указанные в левом кортеже в порядке их записи. Получаем присваивания `a = 2` и `b = 3`.

---

Аналогичное действие можно выполнить, используя следующую последовательность операций:

```
prev = a      # сохраняем предыдущее значение во временной переменной
a = b         # сохраняем текущее значение
b = prev + a  # вычисляем следующее значение как сумму предыдущего и текущего
```